# Create a setting.*.php file for every stage of the website

Tags: 8, configuration, version-control, staging

I understand that my question could be opition-based and that it depends on the comfort of every drupal developer so please do not flag it as so !

For every Drupal 8 website i start, i use the below steps from creating/installing the website to configure it to be used in two stages (Dev & Prod)

***On my Local server:***

On my Windows 10, i have installed Git, Composer and Drush.

**Step 1:**
I download drupal 8 and its dependencies using the famous command:

```
Composer create-project...
```

**Step 2:**

I point Acuia Dev Desktop to my new Drupal 8 composer website by choosing the **import local drupa site** option with below:

- select the **/web** folder
- create a **new** database

**Step 3:**
I launch my drupal 8 composer website using acquia dev desktop and go through the default drupal 8 installer.

**Step 4:**

I copy **default.settings.local.php** from **sites** folder and I paste it into **site/default** folder and then rename it to **settings.dev.php**

**Step 5:** 
I go to the include file (loc_sitename_dd.inc) created by default by Acquia Dev desktop to store the database credentials and other specific configurations and I copy all its contents to **settings.dev.php** file.

**Step 6:**
I go to **settings.php** file and:

- Delete the code within in the  tag created by Acquia dev desktop at the bottom of the file.
- Add the below lines to the bottom of the file to activate two files **settings.dev.php** and **settings.prod.php**

  if (file_exists(**DIR** . '/settings.dev.php')) {
    include **DIR** . '/settings.dev.php';
  }

  if (file_exists(**DIR** . '/settings.prod.php')) {
    include **DIR** . '/settings.prod.php';
  }

**Step 7**
I go to the .gitignore file located one folder above the **web** folder (../sitename) and:

- Remove the line mentioning the **settings.php** file so it will **NOT** be ignored.
- Add the **settings.dev.php** file to be ignored.

**Finally**
The **settings.dev.php** file will have configuration such as:

- Site name.
- Database credentials/configuration.
- Disable Caches.
- Enable rebuild.php
- and many more which are specific only to my **LOCAL HOST** (Dev website)

and will only be available on my Local Server.

***On my Web server***

**Step 1** 
I create a the Production Database with a permissions granted user.

**Step 2**
I upload only one time the **settings.dev.php** file to my web server and I rename it to **settings.prod.php**

**Step 3** 
I edit the *settings.prod.php** file and:

- Change the Site name
- Change the database credentials.
- Enable caches.
- and many more configurations related only to the production (online) website.

**Step 4**
I go to the .gitignore file located one folder above the **web** folder (../sitename) and:

- Remove the line mentioning the **settings.php** file so it will **NOT** be ignored.
- Add the **settings.prod.php** file to be ignored.

**Finally**
The **settings.prod.php** will only be available on my production (online) website.

After all of the above, I start developing my website and push every changes to/from Webserver/Localhost.

Does what i am doing is right/correct ?

Maybe it is not the best method but i would like to ask the experts in this subject about their opinion on my method ?!

Thank you,

Comment: How attached are you to DevDesktop? I really enjoyed it for Drupal 7 sites, but I've  moved away from it for Drupal 8 sites (in favor of Lando). Even on phone calls with Acquia, they didn't seem to recommend it anymore.

Comment: I am not completely attached to DevDesktop but I prefer it compared to MAMP or XAMP because it much easier in install, setup and I really had no problems/errors with it at all ! I just heard about Lando from you so i will give it a shot ! Why not ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong about this. Do whatever fits your needs. I do it somehow similar in my multi-site setups:

I have one global `settings.php` file that's the same across all multi-site instances (I version track this one). Then every instance has its own `settings.site.php` (I version track this one as well). And last but not least every instance has its own `settings.local.php` (that's the only one that's ignored by Git as it holds sensitive and environment-specific information). Both of the latter are included by the global `settings.php`:

```
/**
 * Load site-specific override configuration, if available.
 */
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.site.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.site.php';
}

/**
 * Load local development override configuration, if available.
 */
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

---

I also make heavy use of the `ScriptHandler.php` that's included into [`drupal-composer/drupal-project`](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php). I edited it so it iterates through all multi-site instances and creates a copy of my global `settings.php` in its `createRequiredFiles()` function. And stuff like that. Pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what's the goal you're trying to achieve with all of those steps? The normal process is for the settings.php not to be in your git repo and then you manually upload the settings.php file to each environment and change the database/other configs in the file. It sounds like you're doing all of these steps to get the settings.php file into git, but whats the benefit?

For example you mention about having caching disabled on your dev server. To achieve this you can uncomment very last few lines in settings.php that says to use a settings.local.php file (Which along with the development.services.yml will disable caches and enable rebuild) Those lines can be uncommented on both dev and prod versions of your settings.php and you just dont upload the settings.local.php to your prod server (It would be ignored by the standard .gitignore that comes with drupal)

Comment: _The normal process is for the settings.php not to be in your git repo_ That's the opposite of what my normal process is. If you're on one of the usual suspects for hosting (Acquia/Pantheon), that's also how they expect you to do it too

Comment: I suppose "normal" is a relative term to each person. What I mean is the default/recommended drupal process

Comment: Any chance you have a reference for that? I've been working with Drupal for about 8 years and I haven't seen that advice before! I would imagine if that was a recommended approach settings.php would be excluded via the default .gitignore, but I'm quite sure it isn't

Comment: There’s many ways of doing it really. If you have server control to set the config file outside of project root, go for it. If not, you have to commit it so it gets up there. Acquia provides an include path that goes in settings.php which pulls in connection info, so it must be committed for it to function.

Comment: @Clive, download drupal from https://www.drupal.org/download and you'll see the example.gitignore has sites/*/settings*.php and sites/*/services*.yml

Comment: @Leigh Mason the reason to put my **settings.php** in my git repo is that the settings.php file will hold all configuration which are common to all stages and so if for any reason in the futur I updated/added/removed any configuration from the settings.php file i won't have to remember to update the same configuration in all other stages because **git** will take care of the changes.

Comment: @ElieMasaad And that's a perfectly reasonable approach, if it fits your needs. That's the point - there isn't a right or wrong answer, as long as your process is validated in and of itself, and does what you need it to, then it's correct

Comment: @LeighMason Funny, I must never have looked in that file before. I'm not sure I agree with it as a recommendation, but as I mentioned to Elie, that's kind of the point of something like this - no right or wrong

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that it is not advisable to add settings.php to the git repo only for the reason that such file might include sensitive information like DB credentials but in my case, the DB Credentials are located in settings.*.dev file so it will be totally safe to add settings.php to the git repo.

Comment: @kevin As i mentioned in my question, i deleted the include path added by Acquia Dev Desktop and copy all the include file contents into the settings.*.php and i am doing so because with the include path in the settings.php, drush does not find a connection to the database when used from a Git Bash. (So i had to create the database connection directly into the settings.*.php to help drush connect to the database with no errors.)

Comment: This isn’t a problem, I can use drush just fine with settings connections being included to the file without literally being in the file itself. Otherwise Drush wouldn’t work on setups like Acquia. So that must be something else.

Comment: @Kevin i have tried many solution when drush was throwing me an error similar to this: **the command xxx cannot be executed, drush was unable to execute a query to the database, no connection was found** the only workaround is to have the database credential inside **settings.php** or **settings.*.php** that solved my problem

Comment: It is worth mentioning that inside the include file, there was a setup for the **$settings['hash_salt']** by also Drush was unable to locate them by throwing the error **Missing $settings['hash_salt'] in settings.php**, once i copied all codes from the include file to the *settings.local.php** file and activate it, all errors gone and Drush is working perfectly.... Note: i am using Drush from Git Bash and not from the ugly built-in command line tool provided by Aqcuia desktop